# Express / Jade / Pug: Calling a javascript object's functions

Tags: node.js, express, pug

While I can pass an object's data, I don't know how to pass/call an object's functions.

**route.js:**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  let test = {}; // passing an object called test
  test.hello = function() { //the test object has a method I want to
    console.log('hello');   //call on the browser
  }

  res.render('home.jade', { test:test });
```

**On the .jade page:**

```
//- let test = !{test}; //renders as [object Object]
    let test = !{JSON.stringify(test, null, 4)}; //renders empty obj
    test.hello();
    console.log('test', test);
```

**Console message:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: test.hello is not a function
```

**Rendered source file:**

```
//- let test = [object Object];
let test = {};
test.hello();
console.log('test', test);
```

**An example of what works on my.jade file (what I don't want):**

```
    let test = {};
    test.hello = #{test.hello};
    test.hello();
```

This will console out 'hello'. However, I imagine that there is a way to pass and call an object's function without this workaround.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` will strip away functions since JSON format does not support functions/methods. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> Functions are not a valid JSON data type so they will not work.
>   However, they can be displayed if first converted to a string (e.g. in
>   the replacer), via the function's toString method. Also, some objects
>   like Date will be a string after JSON.parse().

Technically you can use `eval` to evaluate the resulting string to a function, though this is not recommended.